# Maintaining in-app-purchases in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app

I am implementing ios app in which I want to add In-App purchase (IAP).

I want to use in-app purchase for below situation:

1) User will make registration and pay $10.

2) Now, my app will allow user to download songs. (For ex. 10 songs of $1. So user can download 10 songs.)

3) User can add more credit by again making purchase of $10. (So if user wants to pay 2 times then he/she will get $20 in his/her account. And he can download 20 songs of $1.)

4) While downloading song, my app will check whether user has enough balance or not, then only he can download data. (If there is no balance then it will ask to make payment of $10 first.)

I have make research for above situation and also looked into in-app purchase guidelines from Apple.

From that, I come across below:
1) If I will use subscription: But in that case, user will be charged after some duration (for ex. monthly payment, 3 month payment). Which I don't want. Because I want user to pay only if he wants to download data and not have balance. So I think, subscription is not ideal.

2) If I will user Consumable in-app purchase: Here, I can use it, so user can pay as many times as he want. And I need to track his balance from server side. So, from server APIs, I can check user's balance. But I think, it may conflict with Apple rules.

*"Consumable items are the one exception to the requirement that your content be available on all the user’s devices. Consumable items are digital items that are used up or disappear after use and can never be reused. Examples of consumable items include virtual poker chips, in-game ammunition, or virtual supplies such as construction materials."*

So, user can make payment from his iPhone device. And he can download songs from his iPad device as well. Means, purchase is sharable.
But,

Consumables are device-by-device items, so their purchase needs to be made with the understanding that they are tied to the specific device. Apple does not let you restore a purchased consumable. You should warn your users that consumables are not shareable, and make it easy for users to purchase smaller blocks of items.

So can someone helps what kind of in-app purchase is suitable for above and also according to Apple Rules regarding in-app purchase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So...you want to reinvent iTunes again? :D  Non-consumable will let users restore their previous purchase, isn't that what you want ? You want to use in app currency which users buy using in app purchase but at the same time, you also need a server to store user accounts and how much credit they have. Why not use a service like Stripe (http://stripe.com/) to handle the payment ? That way Apple does not get a cut of your in app purchase (which is 30%). I assume you have the copyrights to the songs on your server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Non-consumable will not work in my case. Because I want to add credit to user account. And user can add more credits like $10 three times. So user can have balance of $30. I know that, I will require server to store credit in user's account. But I am confuse about in-app purchase type that which type of in-app purchase will work in my case? Because in case of subscription, it has some duration like 1 month, 3 month, etc. And after that duration, app will again ask user to pay. Can you guide me which is suitable in my scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User "Non-Renewing Subscription" should fit your requirement https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.htm

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am not able to open your URL. It gives "Page not found". Regarding "Non-Renewing Subscription": Is it kind of duration? (like 1 week, 1 month), after which user need to purchase. Do I need to maintain anything on server at my side through which I can know about users points? For ex. $10 = 100 points. And user purchase 3 times then he should have 300 points. So for this, what I need to maintain on server side? And is it sharable? Means can user use his points/credits in all his devices?

Comment: You will have to maintain everything on your server. user can purchase as many times as he wants and yes it allows user to share/restore <https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html> (link won't help much)

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html)

Comment: you need to manage everything using your backend server so yes it can have duration and user can purchase as many times as he wants

Comment: Thanks for link. I read your link and section for "Non-Renewing Subscription". In that, they mentioned that, "Non-renewing subscriptions allow the sale of items with a limited duration.". But I don't want my user to pay me periodically. Or for limited duration. For ex. if user have purchased for $10. And I have given 100 points to user. Then user can use 100 points for unlimited duration. So user can download 2 songs (20 points) 1st month, then 4 songs (40 points) 2nd month, 3 songs (30 points) 3rd month, and so on. Means there is no limited duration. Please share your thought.

Comment: 1) if user purshases for $10 then you will store the transaction on your server (along with time duration if you want)
2) When user purchase that product again then its up to you whether you allow them to restore or purchase again (this is the difference because 'Non-Renewing Subscription' supports restore transaction which you have to call manually)
3) so if same user purchases the same product from another device then you can make them restore instead of purchase again as you have all required data on your server.

it means you are managing everything as per your requirement. hope it helps

Comment: "Apple allow the sale of items with a limited duration" ... doesn't restrict you

Comment: Ok. So for example. (1) User make purchase $10 on 1st Nov. (Do I need to add duration in iTunes like 1 month ? ) (2) I will add 10 points to his account. (3) If user download 6 contents then I will reduce points to 4. (4) Now, user checks his account from other device after November (after 1 month), then first I need to check if user has points (4 points) then he can download content. (5) If user has no point then he need to purchase. Am I right ? So, conclusion is that, even if I have set duration of 1 month, I can use points for unlimited months until it goes to 0. Correct?

Comment: right. it shouldn't ask you to define the time duration while creating such IAP. refer [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial)

Comment: I read tutorial. It is setting duration (3 month, 6 month) for non-renewing subscription.(Which I don't want). What I want is, user pay with in-app purchase and get tokens. Now user can use those tokens till they finished. Once token finished then again user can purchase tokens and use further. So, we don't know, for how much time user will use tokens. He can use 10 tokens for 3 month, 4 month or even 10 month. And once token finished, then app will ask to purchase more tokens. So, in this case, "non-renewing subscription" will work? Sorry, but I want to make make sure and want to confirm.

Comment: While creating non Non-Renewing Subscription product there is no option to specify duration.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am accepting your reply as answer. I hope, "Non-Renewing Subscription" will satisfy my all condition and also according to Apple Rules.